# How do I download this jsFiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

I've forked a JSFiddle and I would like to download all the files including the external libraries. Can someone help? What should I do?

jsfiddle.net/adamschwarcz/1kyfsn6g/

Comment: Why not just copy paste the 3 files ?